# ant: create dirset with all dirs containing files in a fileset

Tags: unit-testing, ant, python-2.7, dirset

Context: a directory, recursively containing python `unittest.TestCase`s:

```
projectdir/build.xml
projectdir/src/x.java
projectdir/distribute/p.jar
projectdir/tests/a/test1.py
projectdir/tests/a/test2.py
projectdir/tests/b/test1.py
projectdir/tests/c/test1.py
projectdir/tests/javaunittests/test2.java
```

And I want ant to call

```
python -m unittest discover -s a b c
```

Now I was trying to convert a `fileset` to the `dirset` of the containing directories?  The idea is to run python unittests:

```
<apply command="python">
   <arg line="-m unittest"/>
   <arg value="-s"/>
   <dirset include="${python_unittests}"/>
</apply>
```

where `${python_unittests}" would refer to a`fileset` (but I don't find how) like this:

```
<fileset id="python_unittests" include="**/*.py">
    <containsregexp expression="\(unittest.TestCase\)"/>
</fileset>
```

Or am I erring, and is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You want all python files with testcases, you don't need a dirset, use :

```
<apply executable="python">
  <arg line="-m unittest"/>
  <arg value="-s"/>
  <fileset dir="projectdir" includes="**/*.py">
    <contains text="unittest.TestCase"/>
  </fileset>
</apply>
```

**EDIT**

Just checked the [docs for unittest on python.org](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html) after your comment.
As i understand it, that should be sufficient :

```
<property name="projectroot" location="foo/bar/yourprojectdir"/>
<exec executable="python" failonerror="true">
 <arg line="-m unittest discover ${projectroot} 'test*.py'"/>
</exec>
```

as python docs section 26.3.3. Test Discovery explains :

```
The -s, -p, and -t options can be passed in as positional arguments in that order. The following two command lines are equivalent:

    python -m unittest discover -s project_directory -p '*_test.py'<br>
    python -m unittest discover project_directory '*_test.py'
```

I expect that discover works recursively starting from project_directory.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good idea, yet the `unittest` module doesn't allow for `xyz.py` as argument - it needs module syntax (a mapper, perhaps?)